# Interviews with staff members about privacy and security policies relevant to their positions

Tags: compliance, urac

I am currently working to help a bunch of small pharmacies remain compliant and one of the requirements is: *Interviews with staff members about privacy and security policies relevant to their positions.*

How do I determine what is relevant to their position or should I just go with a wider range talking about common sense about keep their devices with information secure and protecting client's health information.

Is there a NIST type of document that talks about key points that should be hit?

This is for a [URAC](https://www.urac.org/) compliance.

Compliance areas are:
PHARM Core 13 and Core 15

Comment: Have you got threats written down? Phishing, social engineering etc. ...? Do they know when to escalate? Have you got some horror stories ([Royal prank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_of_Jacintha_Saldanha)) up your sleeve?

Comment: What section of the Standards are you speaking about?

Comment: This would be Core 13 and 15

Answer (score 2):

I don't know URAC, it appears to do with HIPPA based on cursory googling, though I would assume the context of what is trying to be achieved is the same as other sectors (for me finance).

I would say there are three categories that are important:

**General Knowledge:**

This would be everyone's responsibility. A common reference to this is your information security policy used organization wide, internet control polices, and user training around phishing/social engineering attacks. You can even lump best practices here.

**Role Specific knowledge:**

These are polices specific around your job and responsibilities. If you work with PII or medical records (IE you're a DBA) do you know the practices for access into the system, what level encryption or hashing is used, what the difference between PII and public information is.

**Sector/Government Compliance Policy:**

An example of this (for the finance sector) is the ABA, which is company wide training around laws and regulation to provide a check and balances policy. This is usually required by either a group or a government.